# Is it possible to define test dependencies in Spock?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I am trying to achieve similar functionality to the following TestNG code:

```
@Test
public void method1() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "method1" })
public void method2() {}
```

I am unable to find similar concept in Spock. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know such feature in spock, however [`Stepwise`](http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Stepwise.html) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe you want to consider a free tip from someone who has coached many development teams: Don't use it! Tests should be independent of each other. In 99% of all cases you can design your tests to do what you think needs dependencies without actually making them interdependent. Think twice if you believe you need it. And then if you still think you do, reconsider once more. In my last project of 1,500 tests only a single one (1!) had a good justification for `@Stepwise`, and it was a Geb test, not a pure Spock test.